# Web Scraping with Try: Except: in For Loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written the code below attempting to practice web-scraping with Python, Pandas, etc. In general I have four steps I am trying to follow to achieve my desired output:

1. Get a list of names to append to a base url
2. Create a list of player specific urls
3. Use the player urls to scrape tables
4. add the player name to the table I scraped to keep track of which player belongs to which stats - so in each row of the table add a column with the players name who was used to scrape the table

I was able to get #'s 1 and 2 working.  The components of #3 seem to work, but i believe i have  something wrong with my try: except because if i run just the line of code to scrape a specific  playerUrl the tables DF populates as expected.  The first player scraped has no data so I believe I am failing with the error catching.

For # 4 i really havent been able to find a solution.  How do i add the name to the list as it is iterating in the for loop?

Any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



### get the player data to create player specific urls

res = requests.get("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
data = soup.find('div', class_ = 'item-list' )

names=[]


for player in data:
    name = data.find_all('div', class_ = 'name')
    for obj in name:
        names.append(obj.find('a').text.lower().lstrip().rstrip().replace(' ','-'))


### create a list of player specific urls
url = 'https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/'
playerUrl = []
x = 0
for name in (names):
    playerList = names
    newUrl = url + str(playerList[x])
    print("Gathering url..."+newUrl)
    playerUrl.append(newUrl)
    x +=1

### now take the list of urls and gather stats tables

tbls = []
i = 0
for url in (playerUrl):
    try:                                                        ### added the try, except, pass because some players have no stats table
        tables = pd.read_html(playerUrl[i], header = 0)[2]
        tbls.append(tables)
        i +=1
    except Exception:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do couple of things to improve your code and get the step # 3 and 4 done.

(i) When using the `for name in names` loop, there is no need to explicitly use the indexing, just use the variable name. 
(ii) You can save the player's name and its corresponding URL as a dict, where the name is the key. Then in step 3/4 you can use that name
(iii) Construct a DataFrame for each parsed HTML table and just append the player's name to it. Save this data frame individually.
(iv) Finally [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) these data frames to form a single one.

Here is your code modified with above suggested changes:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



### get the player data to create player specific urls

res = requests.get("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
data = soup.find('div', class_ = 'item-list' )

names=[]

for player in data:
    name = data.find_all('div', class_ = 'name')
    for obj in name:
        names.append(obj.find('a').text.lower().lstrip().rstrip().replace(' ','-'))


### create a list of player specific urls
url = 'https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/'
playerUrl = {}
x = 0
for name in names:
    newUrl = url + str(name)
    print("Gathering url..."+newUrl)
    playerUrl[name] = newUrl

### now take the list of urls and gather stats tables

tbls = []
for name, url in playerUrl.items():
    try:                                                        
        tables = pd.read_html(url, header = 0)[2]
        df = pd.DataFrame(tables)
        df['Player'] = name
        tbls.append(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue

result = pd.concat(tbls)
print(result.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of redundancy in your script. You can clean them up complying the following. I've used `select()` instead of `find_all()` to shake of the verbosity in the first place. To get rid of that `IndexError`, you can make use of `continue` keyword like I've shown below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=0"
url = 'https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/'

res = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
names = []
for player in soup.select('.item-list .name a'):
    names.append(player.get_text(strip=True).replace(" ","-"))

playerUrl = {}
for name in names:
    playerUrl[name] = f'{url}{name}'

tbls = []
for url in playerUrl.values():
    if len(pd.read_html(url))<=2:continue
    tables = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[2]
    tbls.append(tables)

print(tbls)
```

Comment: thanks for this!  i wasn't aware of the select() option instead of find_all.